# About Laughlin's argument in IQHE

Tags: quantum-hall-effect

If Laughlin's argument for IQHE is a non-interacting picture, then why it still works?

Besides, what is the relation between Laughlin and Halperin's approach and TKNN (also the later work by Niu and Thouless)?